# Running Grunt Typescript from MSBuild

Tags: msbuild, gruntjs, msbuild-task

I have a typescript project set up that is being built with GruntJS using the typescript plugin. I also have a Visual Studio project that I'd like to be able to invoke the build process from.

My first attempt at doing this was adding an `<Exec>` task to the BeforeBuild target in visual studio, with the `<Exec>` task configured like this:

`<Exec Command="grunt --no-color typescript" />`

This runs the build fine, however, when errors are output from Grunt and they populate the Error List in VS, the filename is incorrectly listed as EXEC.

Looking at the [Exec Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8zx72cd.aspx) I see that `CustomErrorRegularExpression` is a parameter to the command, but I can't quite grasp how to use it to solve my problem.

I messed around with it a bit and managed to change the reported filename to my .jsproj file, which is also incorrect. Looking at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397972/compiling-many-typescript-files-at-once-resulted-in-file-not-found-error) I tried forming my own regex:

`<Exec CustomErrorRegularExpression="\.ts\([0-9]+,[0-9]+\):(.*)" Command="grunt --no-color typescript" IgnoreExitCode="true" />`

Does anyone have any experience using this command with this parameter to achieve this sort of thing? I think maybe part of the problem is that grunt is printing out errors in two lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the Exec task only processing single line messages.  In addition it also uses `Regex.IsMatch` to evaluate the error/warning condition, without making use of the pattern's capture groups.

I was not able to find a way to work around this via MSBuild, but the changes to correct the problem were easy to make directly in the grunt task.

I'm using the grunt-typescript task from: https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-typescript.

There were 3 trivial changes necessary to make this work.

**1) Replace the output utility methods near the top of `tasks/typescript.js`:**

```js
/* Remove the >> markers and extra spacing from the output */
function writeError(str) {
  console.log(str.trim().red);
}

function writeInfo(str) {
  console.log(str.trim().cyan);
}
```

**2) Replace `Compiler.prototype.addDiagnostic` to write the file and error data on the same line:**

```js
Compiler.prototype.addDiagnostic = function (diagnostic) {
  var diagnosticInfo = diagnostic.info();
  if (diagnosticInfo.category === 1)
    this.hasErrors = true;

  var message = "  ";
  if (diagnostic.fileName()) {
    message = diagnostic.fileName() + 
      "(" + (diagnostic.line() + 1) + "," + (diagnostic.character() + 1) + "): ";
  }

  this.ioHost.stderr.Write(message + diagnostic.message());
};
```

Once these changes are made, you no longer need the `CustomErrorRegularExpression` to be set on your Exec task, and your build output should display the error text including the correct source file with line and column information.

Comment: Nice! I didn't think of modifying the grunt task itself.